# How to do type generics with arrays in java?

Tags: java, generics, types, polymorphism

In java I want to make a function that takes a list of any type of contents, and then returns an array of that same type. I got so far

```
public static <T>[] listToArray(List<T> items) {
    <T>[] names = new <T>[items.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i+=1) {
        names[i] = items.get(i);
    }
    return names;
}
```

But this has lots of syntax errors...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: there is already `toArray(T[]a)` and `toArray()` in `List`

Answer (score 6):

From *Effective Java* by Bloch, Item 25:

> ...arrays and generics have very different type rules. Arrays are
>   covariant and reified; generics are invariant and erased. As a
>   consequence, arrays provide runtime type safety but not compile-time
>   type safety and vice versa for generics. Generally speaking, arrays
>   and generics don’t mix well. If you find yourself mixing them and
>   getting compile-time errors or warnings, your first impulse should be
>   to replace the arrays with lists.

**Explanations:**

**Arrays are covariant means** that if class `Dog` extends class `Animal` then you can do:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
animals[0] = new Dog();
```

The same does NOT apply to Generics since generics are *invariant*:

```
List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<Animal>();
animals.add(new Dog()); // compilation error!!!
```

**Arrays are reified means** that all the information about the array type will be available during runtime as well as compile time. Again, Generics are erased which means that the type information is there only during compile time.

Comment: @omega that means you cant do `T[] names = new T[items.size()];` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, you need to pass a second argument (the Class of T) to your method like so,

```
public static <T> T[] listToArray(List<T> items, Class<T> cls) {
  T[] names = (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, items.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i += 1) {
    names[i] = items.get(i);
  }
  return names;
}
```

So that you can use [`Array.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html), from the tutorial -

> Just as in non-reflective code, reflection supports the ability to dynamically create arrays of arbitrary type and dimensions via [`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-).

This is required because the type `T` is erased at run-time. By passing in the Class you can work around this restriction.

Comment: `T[] names = (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, items.size());`